# Using flask to run SQL command & output results as CSV download

Tags: python, sql, flask

idea:

- take id's from html input
- use id's to run sql and return relevant usernames
- download the output as a csv on the front end when the "download" button is clicked

**html**

```
Enter comma delimited ids <input type="text" id="text1" name="text1"><br><br>
<a href="/getPlotCSV">download</a>
```

**python**

```
@app.route("/getPlotCSV", methods=['GET','POST'])
def getPlotCSV():
    text1 = request.form['text1']
    result = {}

    a = []
    x = []

    a.extend([str(x) for x in text1.split(",")])
    format_strings = ','.join(['%s'] * len(a))
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    sql = "SELECT DisplayName FROM dbo.[Users] where id IN ({seq})".format(
        seq=','.join(['?'] * len(a)))
    cursor.execute(sql,a)
    for row, in cursor:
        x.append(row)

    csv = x

    return Response(
        csv,
        mimetype="text/csv",
        headers={"Content-disposition":
                 "attachment; filename=myplot.csv"})
```

The sql and input works because i have tested it separately without the csv download and it returns the correct data. The error i get at the moment is "400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand." KeyError: 'text1'

what am i missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The `KeyError` is because you haven't actually passed the value of `text1` to your `getPlotCSV` route. A link on an HTML page won't also transfer the data with it. Instead you need to use a form with an action page, like this:

```html
<form action="/getPageCSV" method="post">
  Enter comma delimited ids: <input type="text" id="text1" name="text1">
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

This should then pass those values to the url in the form `action` attribute, in this case your `getPageCSV`. It doesn't have to be POST, I've just done that as an example.

Then, when your route receives the data:

```py
@app.route('/getPageCSV')
def getPlotCSV():
    if request.method == "POST": #in other words, if the form is being submitted
      text1 = request.form.get('text1') #use dict.get in case it isn't there
      
      # your code 

      csv = x
      return redirect(url_for('getPlotCSV')) #this time a get method
    return Response(
        csv,
        mimetype="text/csv",
        headers={"Content-disposition":
                 "attachment; filename=myplot.csv"})
```

The above won't specifically work without you adding in your own way to move the POST process data/csv over to when the user is redirected. You could do it as a request header, store it in the session storage or even put it in the query string, it's up to you, but you have to be able to display the results of your POST process into a GET request when the user is redirected.